# Can't upgrade SSH2 with pecl

Tags: php, pear, pecl

My current version of pecl SSH2 is 0.12 and I am trying to upgrade it to 0.13.

I tried both:

```
pecl upgrade ssh2-0.13
```

and

```
pecl install ssh2-0.13
```

and got

```
ERROR: pecl.php.net/ssh2 not installed
```

Not much feedback, what else can I try?

using php 5.6 and PEAR 1.9.5

Comment: What does `pecl list-upgrades` show?

Comment: Did you resolve it? I am getting exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

I am using **CentOS** and following helped me to upgrade, might help you too

```
yum install gcc php-devel php-pear libssh2 libssh2-devel
// or in ubuntu(deb) sudo apt-get install ...............
```

**`pecl install -f ssh2`**

Actually i removed my old version and did above. And i installed all the packages that require. Please make sure you have installed all the required  packages (**gcc, php-devel, php-pear, libssh2, libssh2-devel**) and then try to install or upgrade again.